# How to check if order is reorder or new?

Tags: magento-1.9, script, reorder

We have a magento 1.9 site.
When new order place we want to check this order is reordered or not using a custom PHP file.
Anyone help me to create this script.

Comment: What kind of reorder ? Is it Reorder from Admin side or customer side ?

Comment: All order are from Customer side.

Comment: I think you are asking of it is a repeat order. Where do you want to display if repeat or not?